# how to check the status of boolean field in django views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm using django 1.11.3.

The `model.py` file:

```
class Corso(models.Model):
titolo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
progressivo= models.BooleanField(default=False)

f1= models.BooleanField(default=False)
f2= models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.titolo)
```

The `views.py` file:

```
def edit_iscrizioni(request, corso_id):
corsi = Corso.objects.filter( pk=corso_id)
tabella= Iscrizione.objects.filter(user=request.user)
iscrizione=get_object_or_404(Iscrizione, pk=tabella)

f1=CreaCorsi.objects.values_list("f1")

print f1

if request.method == "POST":
    form = IscrizioneForm(request.POST, instance= iscrizione)
    if form.is_valid():
        iscrizione = form.save(commit=False)
        iscrizione.user = request.user
        iscrizione.published_date = timezone.now()
        iscrizione.corso1_id= corso_id
        iscrizione.save()


    return redirect('privata')

else:
    form = IscrizioneForm(instance= iscrizione)
return render(request, 'corsi/edit.html', {'form':form, 'corsi':corsi})
```

How to make a `view.py` with this logic?

```
if Corso.f1==True:
```

I know `x=Corso.objects.filter(f1=True)` but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Simply dumping code instead of explaining logic is asking to be skipped by people who may be able to help you.

Comment: @StarShine  i want save "IscrizioneForm" in a different way fi corsi.f1== True of Falce

Comment: Please edit white space to get a valid Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is vague but if I understand correctly, you are getting the right object with this line :

```
corsi = Corso.objects.filter(pk=corso_id)
```

So if your goal is to compare his `f1` attribute, why not using :

```
if corsi.f1:
    #do something when True
```

**EDIT**

Sorry it was my mistake, the line you use return a Queryset,

```
corsi = Corso.objects.filter(pk=corso_id)
```

Therefore use this:

```
corsi = Corso.objects.get(pk=corso_id)
```

Which will result in an instance and then use my conditional code.

Another alternative would be to use built-in [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#first) this will add a validation to check if the object exists. Then, you have to decide what you want to do if it is `None`. Use it like this:

```
corsi = Corso.objects.filter(pk=corso_id).first()
```

Comment: this error is returned to me 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'f1'